# PDF signing service with trusted timestamp without user interaction

Tags: pdf, document, digital-signature, digital-certificate, trusted-timestamp

I am looking for service (having public API - REST or SOAP) for digitally signing documents (mainly PDF). In the best case with existing SDK.

I found a lot of services but all of them enforce user interaction in browser. I need to do everything in the background and at the end provide signed document.

It could be commercial service that requires a fee.

Can anybody recommend that service?

Comment: I'm not sure whether or not such recommendations are on topic here. If they are, though, you should also mention your requirements, especially concerning the required legal value of the signature and time stamp.

Comment: You could try www.universign.eu.

Comment: I know it is more survey/support then thechnical issue.  But I think that here are a lot of people having an experience with commercial signing services.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at SignServer, which supports PDF signing (among other) and has a web services (SOAP) interface and a simple HTTP POST interface that can be used pragmatically:
https://www.signserver.org/

SignServer is Open Source Software and is also available in an Enterprise Edition with commercial support from [PrimeKey](https://www.primekey.se/technologies/products-overview/signserver-enterprise/).